# Holomorphic function is injective

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

Let $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function where $\Omega:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}; -1<Re(z)<|Im(z)|\}$ (i.e. $\Omega$ is open, connected, non-convex). If

$|f'(z)-1|<1/4$

then $f$ is injective on $\Omega$.

PS.:
1)It is obvious that it is gonna be locally injective since $f'(z)\neq 0$, $\forall z\in\Omega$ (using b)... but how can I guarantee that it is gonna be for whole $\Omega$?

2) If $\Omega$ is convex it is trivial:

In fact, suppose that $a\neq b$ s.t $f(a)=f(b)$. So, consider the straight line $\gamma$, connecting $a$ to $b$, i.e. $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \Omega$ is defined as $\gamma (t)=a+(b-a)t$. Since $\Omega$ is convex, this line lies in $\Omega$ and so $f$ is holomorphic here. Thus,

$0=f(b)-f(a)=\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}f'(z)dz=\int_{0}^{1}f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}f'(a+(b-a)t)(b-a)dt$

As $(b-a)\in\mathbb{C}^{*}$ is just a constant (non-zero since $a\neq b$, by assumption). We have:

$\displaystyle0=\int_{0}^{1}f'(a+(b-a)t)dt$ $\Rightarrow \displaystyle -1=\int_{0}^{1}(f'(a+(b-a)t)-1)dt $ (adding (-1) both sides). Now, Taking the module, we have

$1=\displaystyle|\int_{0}^{1}(f'(a+(b-a)t)-1)dt|\leq \int_{0}^{1}|(f'(a+(b-a)t)-1)|dt<\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{4}dt=\frac{1}{4}$ (we have to use the assumption here for the last inequality). So, $1<\frac{1}{4}$, Contradiction. Therefore, $f(a)\neq f(b)$, i.e. $f$ is injective. $\square$

$\Omega$:
[image]

Comment: what is known about $\Omega$? In trivial cases ($\Omega$ has more than one component) this is not true, so I would assume it's at least connected. Is it assumed that with $z$ also $z+1$ in $\Omega$, or does a) only hold for those $z$ for which this is true (then the condition may be empty)?

Comment: If you have additional information about $\Omega$ you should include that in your question (you can edit your question).

Comment: I added it! Thks for the comments!

Comment: You still haven't addressed Thomas' question about (a). Is $\Omega$ required to also satisfy $\Omega + 1 \subseteq \Omega$, or does (a) only hold for $z \in \Omega \cap (\Omega - 1)$?

Comment: Actually, I've changed $\Omega$ to be a easy domain to visualize it but my idea to write a strip was a super bad idea, since it is convex. And convex is a trivial case. Now, you know everything about $\Omega$ I also drew a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your revised problem, note that there are various "large" convex subsets of $\Omega.$ In each of those $f$ is injective as we've seen. Play around a bit with these and you'll see that we can reduce the problem to this: If $a\in \Omega\cap \{y>|x|\},$ $b\in \Omega\cap \{y<-|x|\},$ then $f(a)\ne f(b).$

To prove this, let $a=a_1+ia_2, b=b_1+ib_2.$ Choose $0 < \epsilon < \min(1,a_2,|b_2|).$

Then

$$\tag 1 f(a)-f(-\epsilon) = \int_{[-\epsilon,a]}f'(z)\,dz = (a+\epsilon)\int_0^1 f'(-\epsilon + t(a+\epsilon))\,dt.$$

Now by the assumption on $f',$ the last integral has the form $A_1+iA_2,$ where $A_1>3/4$ and $|A_2|<1/4.$ We can write $(1)=(a_1+\epsilon +ia_2)(A_1+iA_2).$ The imaginary part of this is

$$ (a_1+\epsilon)A_2 + a_2A_1 >-2|a_1||A_2|+ a_2A_1 > -2a_2(1/4) + a_2(3/4) = a_2/4>0.$$

You can verify in a similar way that the imaginary part of $f(b)-f(-\epsilon)$ is less than $b_2/4<0.$ Thus

$$f(a)-f(b)=f(a) - f(-\epsilon) - (f(b)-f(-\epsilon))$$

has positive imaginary part. This shows $f(a)\ne f(b)$ as desired.

I don't see that we need a) in this problem.

---

Prvious answer: You've gone from a difficult question to an easy one with your edit. Here is a well known result: Suppose $\Omega$ is open and convex, and that $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega,$ with $\text { Re } f' > 0$ in $\Omega.$ Then $f$ is injective. Proof: Just do what @ArnaudMortier did. Here his proof idea will work because you can take $\gamma$ to be a straight line segment. I'll leave the verification to you.

The assumptions on $f$ in your question are overkill. Your $\Omega$ is a vertical strip, hence is convex. And b) gives $\text { Re } f' > 0$ (and a lot more). We don't need a) at all.

Comment: Actually, I've changed $\Omega$ to be a easy domain to visualize it but my idea to write a strip was a super bad idea, since it is convex. And convex is  a trivial case. My $\Omega$ is well defined now, and and drew a picture and I wrote some P.s's that I know.

Comment: I guess your equation (1) is wrong. It should be: inside the integral $f'(-\epsilon +t(a+\epsilon)$ . Moreover, $A_1=A_1(z)$ and $A_2=A_2(z)$... Sorry, I didn't get it... It wasn't clear for me.

Comment: When I first tried this, I thought $-1/2$ could be used for all $a,b$ but later I realized that didn't work. So I chose an $\epsilon$ that depends on $a,b$ but left the $-1/2$ in by mistake. I'll edit.

Comment: On the integrals: you seem to forget we're integrating over $[0,1]$ at the point where $A_1,A_2$ are introduced.

Comment: If you integrate a function that is $> 3/4$ over $[0,1],$ the integral is a number $>3/4.$

Comment: It's right! perfect! Now, I am thinking to do it in another way!